# HTML/PHP Getting an input to POST and be read by a PHP statement

Tags: php, select, post, input, get

I've read numerous posts and am so close to getting this to work, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the shortened version of my code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table id="box-table-a" summary="PM Summary" style='width:90%'>
<tr>
<th>Update</th>
<th style='width:20%'>PM Comments </th>
<th>PMM Recommendations</th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$PMComments         = $row['PMComments'];
$PMMRecommendations = $row['PMMRecommendations'];
?>

<tr>
<td><input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update"></td>
<td><?= $PMComments ?><input name="PMComments" type="text" value="<?= $PMComments ?>"></td>
<td><?= $PMMRecommendations ?><value="<?= $PMMRecommendations ?>">      
        <select name="PMMRecommendations">
            <option value="null"></option>
            <option value="No Action Taken">No Action Taken</option>
        </select>    
</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

Then, below this, I have this section:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
$PMCommentsValue         = $_GET["PMComments"];
$PMMRecommendationsValue = $_GET["PMRecommendations"];


printf("PMComments: %s ", $PMCommentsValue);
echo "<br>";
printf("PMRecommendations: %s ", $PMMRecommendationsValue);
?>
```

The table is displaying correctly, but I am confused because what I think I'm doing, and what is happening, and are the same.  Once I make a change to the text field created by the PM Comments input, and hit submit, I want the value that I entered to be transmitted into the variable

I know that the next section of code:

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {............
```

is running, because once I hit submit I see the two printf()s below, but they're blank, meaning I am not actually transmitting any data to them.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your form is POSTing:

```
<form method="post"
```

but you're trying to access the data from the GET array:

```
$PMCommentsValue         = $_GET["PMComments"];
$PMMRecommendationsValue = $_GET["PMRecommendations"];
```

change those to both using the POST array and you'll be fine:

```
$PMCommentsValue         = $_POST["PMComments"];
$PMMRecommendationsValue = $_POST["PMRecommendations"];
```

Generally the GET array refers to the URL (eg. index.php?PMComments=hello") and the POST array is normally form data (although you can have GET forms... but hey!)

Comment: Thanks! Technically, this works - What's happening now though is it's just feeding back the value that was already IN the cell.  So - the first row of the table is auto-populating with whatever I have in the SQL database for that specific comment, like "Call Dave".  I change this to "I called Dave, he wasn't home."  Then I click Submit, and the output is still "Call Dave."  Same thing with the dropdown - it's not "saving" my work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I'm wrong - it's passing whatever changes I make to the very last row that is displayed.  Right now my SQL query looks like this:    
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM report WHERE PMName = '$PMSelection' AND REGNSB <> 0.000 ORDER BY RegNSB DESC Limit 5");

so I'm only showing 5 values.  The only one that successfully posts is the 5th one - why is this?  Do I need to use arrays to give each instance of PMComments and PMMRecommendations a unique value?